# How can I remove and return the first element in an ActiveRecord relation object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to remove and return the first element in an AR relation object. I used [shift](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-shift), but it does not remove the object.

With a normal array, shift works as expected:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a.shift # => 1
a # => [2, 3]
```

This does not work. The variable `@attachment_versions` retains the same size before and after using `shift`.

```
@attachment = Attachment.with_associations.find(params[:id])
@attachment_versions = @attachment.attachment_versions
@current_version = @attachment_versions.shift

# this raises `true`
raise @attachment_versions.include?(@current_version).to_s

def self.with_associations
  includes(attachment_versions: :owner, comments: [:author, :attachments])
end
```

I know that an AR relation object is more than just an Array, but I thought `shift` should work in the same way.

Comment: Could you be more specific? How are you generating the AR object? Is it a `where` clause? And are you expecting the `shift` to modify the underlying database, or are you just wanting to manipulate a list of AR records locally?

Comment: @mbratch I added my model code.

Comment: That's great. Could you answer the other questions, since it makes a difference.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? Because `shift` on an AR relation object works as expected here with Rails 4.

Comment: You could try `attachment_versions = @attachment.attachment_versions.to_a`, then `@current_version = attachment_versions.shift`. This assumes you are just wanting to do things with the array locally and not interested in this mechanism changing the underlying data (*i.e.*, deleting a record when you do the `shift`).

Comment: @mbratch sorry, I did not understand your question. I don't think I'm doing anything weird with my query.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you're doing anything weird. I'm just asking whether you're wanting to do things locally or with the database. Both are perfectly valid and normal. Just different.

Comment: @mbratch I want to do it locally.

Comment: @zwippie I am using Rails 4.

Comment: @mbratch Ok, thanks. I will try your suggestion. I'm not sure what impact this will have on my rendering the data in the view, though. If I want to display other associations, for example, `version.owner.name`.

Comment: All those details are important when describing a problem since they can govern what the solution needs to be. But check my question out about possible duplicate values in the array. Maybe you should do a debug dump of the array out to check, not just the `raise` since the latter isn't a complete check. Or at least do a before and after check of the length of the array to see if the `shift` removed something. Does what's in `@current_version` occur more than once in your array? That could cause your `raise` to show `true` even if the `shift` works as expected.

Comment: @mbatch I checked the array size before and after and it's the same. I am sure there are no duplicates too. The array size confirms that shift is not removing the element. I also test this in my terminal and the same result.

Answer (score 3):

You can pretty easily turn it into an array first.

i.e.

```
@attachment_versions_array = @attachment_versions.to_a

@attachment_versions_array.shift
=> <Attachment_version......etc
```